# Netsuite: How to set a particular value of a custom custom segment having a particular custom record type?

Tags: netsuite, erp, suitetalk, netsuite-rest-api

I have a custom segment in Netsuite having internalId = 4 (see the URL). It has an ID = cseg_jg_project and record ID = customrecord_cseg_jg_project. This custom segment looks like this in the Netsuite UI and has multiple values like "Test project", "24-041-06" etc. as shown below:

[image]

The custom record it is referring to has internal ID  = 1384 (see the URL) and has ID = "customrecord_cseg_jg_project" and shows the above custom segment in the field "ORIGINATING CUSTOM SEGMENT" (see below):

[image]

Now I am trying to set the value of this custom segment as "24-041-06" (i.e the 2nd value in list of custom segment) via the following portion in payload:

```
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "internalId": "4",
                            "xsi:type": "platformCore:SelectCustomFieldRef",
                            "scriptId": "customrecord_cseg_jg_project"
                        },
                        "platformCore:value": {
                            "attributes": {
                                "internalId": "2",
                                "typeId": "1384"
                            },
                            "platformCore:name": "24-041-06"
                        }
                    }
```

Though I am able to successfully execute the API call, the Project # custom segment is not getting set with the desired value and stays blank in Netsuite. What is the issue with this payload?